# FastPass report with screenshot

Tags: android, accessibility-insights

Is it possible to export Accessibility Insights for Android FastPass reports not only with issue description but also with screenshot?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It isn't currently possible, but we have an [active feature request](https://github.com/microsoft/accessibility-insights-web/issues/2770) for this functionality in our repo. If this is something you'd like to see us add, please upvote the feature request so we know there's community interest.